# CakePHP hasOne relationship multiple savings

Tags: cakephp

I need some help with a hasOne relationship that is saving multiple records with the same foreign key. The relationship is:

`Personal` belongsTo `UserAccount`

`UserAccount` hasOne `Personal`

In the table named `personals` I've put the foreign key to `user_accounts`, which is called `user_account_id`, and the restriction only works if I manually select in my database this foreign key as Unique.

I thought CakePHP can manage this situations. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

In my add form I have the line `echo $this->Form->input('UserAccount.id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $useraccount_id));` where `$useraccount_id` is taken from my `UserAccountsController`:

```
 public function new_personal() {

    $current_user = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $current_account = $this->UserAccount->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('UserAccount.user_id' => $current_user)));
    $this->set('useraccount_id', $current_account['UserAccount']['id']);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            unset($this->UserAccount->Personal->validate['user_account_id']);
            $this->UserAccount->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ok'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error'));
    }
}
```

I've also tried to add the `unique => true` property to the hasOne and belongsTo relationships (on my models) but it didn't work. The only way I find is to set the Unique key directly in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You must set ID of Personal row durring edit.
Additional set the UNIQUE KEY od field user_account_id in Your table

Comment: Hi kicaj, thanks for your answer. Please check my edit. What do you think?